# Visual Studio 2013 C# Interactive Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, window, visual-studio-2013, interactive

Is there C# interactive window for VS 2013, or any other similar way, without installing VS 2012.
I tried C# Repel, C# Snippet Compiler and Mono Command Prompt, but, all of them don't provide the features of C# interactive window packed with Roslyn for VS 2012.

Comment: Keep track of this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/0da45fe7-fbe2-4074-b52f-dc8d7c4b2ba3/c-interactive-in-vs-2013 I guess when something comes out it will appear there first.

Comment: I've already found that article... Wasn't there any official announcement?

Comment: No that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# interactive finally arrived to VS 2015... You may need to install vs2015.1 to get it..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx

Good luck... and happy interactive coding!

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** Found a total better alternative!!! Try **[CShell](http://cshell.net/)**, it is free and open source! **"A simple, yet powerful, C# scripting IDE"** as they promote it.
Check **[my tweet](https://twitter.com/fabifernandez23/status/502840417914998784)** which was also favorited by Scott Hanselman :)

My old recommendation was: **[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)**

Comment: It appears to be for SQL queries only, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it works with everything you want of the language. Check the docs. You can even import your own assemblies to use just like Roslyn.

Comment: Indeed, it's not exactly interactive, you write your code then run it... not working interactively.

Comment: Just for other readers: past comments were talking about LINQPad, not CShell.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to install VS 2012 and use C# interactive window provided with its Roslyn. While doing that, wait Microsoft to release C# interactive to VS 2013.

Comment: Can you please provide any link?

Comment: VS 2012.4: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305
VS 2012 SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668
Roslyn CTP: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685

Comment: This is so great. Can't wait for the RTM of Roslyn! I'm on VS2013.4.

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from one of the links above:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/0da45fe7-fbe2-4074-b52f-dc8d7c4b2ba3/c-interactive-in-vs-2013

It worked for me, so hopefully this will help the next person :)

> Hi SpencerGR,
>
> I just got upgraded to VS 2013 and wanted C# Interactive, and this is
>   the first hit when I searched for it, so I figured I would place my
>   answer here...
>
> Didn't make sense to me that the extension from VS 2012 wouldn't work;
>   so I hunted down the Roslyn keys in my registry for VS 2012 and was
>   able to kinda figure out what was going on. After a bit of futzing
>   around, I finally got it working, so here's the instructions for
>   whoever might care to try [be warned, I'm sure this isn't supported by
>   MS, I take no responsibility if something happens to mess up your
>   computer, and so forth ;)].
>
> Basically it was a matter of
>
> copying some registry keys with slight modification copying some files
>   and this one is annoying but oh, well] there's a file you have to
>   change the datestamp on (I did it by opening the file in Notepad++ and
>   saving it out.)  If you don't already have VS 2012 or you don't have
>   the Roslyn CTP installed you'll need to get the files somehow, and I'm
>   not sure if there are other registry settings needed or not, but I
>   imagine if you just manage to get the files out of the CTP distro it
>   would be enough... No guarantees of course.
>
> ---
>
> Not-Instructions-Just-An-Explanation-Of-What-I-Did-I-Am-A-Trained-Professional-...-Or-Something
>   ;)
>
> 1. copying some registry keys with slight modification; I replaced '11.0' with '12.0' in the keys and values, you might need to change
>      the paths too if you didn't install Visual Studio in it's default
>      location. (also posted to pastebin.com/XeP5ai8F )

Save this as a .reg file and open it to import the new keys easily:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\InteractiveWindows\0] "ContentType"="Roslyn C#"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\InstalledProducts\Roslyn] ""="Microsoft Roslyn CTP" "ProductDetails"="Microsoft Roslyn CTP"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{c5edd1ee-c43b-4360-9ce4-6b993ca12897}] "Class"="Roslyn.VisualStudio.CSharp.Repl.CSharpReplPackage" "CodeBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Roslyn C# Interactive Window\\1.2.20906.1\\Roslyn.VisualStudio.CSharp.Repl.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{f5199a4e-6a60-4f79-82e9-fc92a41c4610}] "Class"="Roslyn.VisualStudio.InteractiveWindow.InteractiveWindowPackage" "CodeBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Roslyn Components\\1.2.20906.1\\Roslyn.VisualStudio.InteractiveWindow.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\ToolWindows\{2d0a56aa-9527-4b78-b6e6-ebe6e05da749}] "Name"="Roslyn.VisualStudio.InteractiveWindow.VsInteractiveWindow"
```

> 2. copying some files; basically just need to copy the files mentioned above to the locations mentioned above; I just copied the
>      'Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Roslyn C# Interactive Window' and
>      'Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Roslyn Components' folders from my
>      11.0 install to my 12.0 install. easy peasy.
> 3. and yeah... there's a file in the aforementioned 'Common7\IDE\Extensions' directory called
>      'extensions.configurationchanged'; I couldn't get things to take, then
>      I noticed that file. so, as mentioned, I just opened in Notepad++ and
>      saved back out; I think I had to make a change to the file, so I added
>      a space. kinda felt kludgy, but I guess it beats VS taking longer to
>      load due to having to scan the Extensions every time you open it up.
>
> ---
>
> So, that's it! Worked for me, I hope someone else may find this
>   useful, as it probably took longer to post this than it did to
>   actually get it working in the first place. ;) It's possible I missed
>   a step in here somewhere, since I had made a few other attempts before
>   I found the 'changed' file, so I could have possibly twiddled another
>   bit somewhere that was necessary that I don't remember. Should be a
>   good start tho.
>
> I haven't tested it out fully by any means but it shows up in the
>   'View > Other Windows' list, it opens up just find, and it looks like
>   Intellisense is working too. Good luck and great code to all! :)
>
> --- Chelle L.

Comment: I've managed to run this in VS 2013, but not in VS 2015, have you tried it in VS 2015?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). You can use it to test C# code. It has built in support for loading DLLs and Nuget Packages. Its what I use personally and I love it.

It has a free version, but the paid version has intellisense and debugger

Answer (score 1):

IWIH describes how to install it and which prerequisites you need.

Let me give you some

### **Additional information:**

After you have installed **VS 2015 and its updates (update 3 KB3165756 patch has just arrived)** you can bring **C# interactive** to your screen as follows:

Either via the menu

> View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive

Or press **Ctrl + Q** and type into the **quick launch** box:

> C# interactive

which allows you to click on `View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive` with the mouse.

Afterwards, you have the `C# Interactive` beneath the error list. Here is an example how you can use it:

[image]

**Quickstart:**

- To get help in this window, type `#help` and press enter.
- To execute a statement, simply press `ENTER`. To type in multiple lines, press `SHIFT+ENTER` for each line, and for the last line press `ENTER` to execute the entire statement.
- To print the values of a variable, type its name and press enter (in the screen shot, I have done this for variable `q`)